# Print unicode character string in R

Tags: r, unicode

I entered a text string in `.csv` file , which includes unicode symbols as: `\U00B5` g/dL. 
In `.csv` file as well as read in R data frame:

[image]

```
test=read.csv("test.csv")
```

[image]

`\U00B5` would produce the micro sign- µ. R read it into data file as it is (`\U00B5`). However when I print the string it shows as `\\U00B5 g/dL`.
Alternatively, manually entering the code works fine.

```
varname <- c("a", "b", "c")
labels <- c("A \U00B5 g/dL", "B \U00B5 g/dL", "C \U00B5 g/dL")
df <- data.frame(varname, labels)
test <- data.frame(varname, labels)
test
#  varname   labels
#  1       a A µ g/dL
#  2       b B µ g/dL
#  3       c C µ g/dL
```

I wonder how could I get rid of the escape sign `\` in this case and have it print out the symbol. 
Or, if there another way to print out the symbol in R.

Thank you very much for this help!

Comment: When you say, *However when I print the string it shows as `\\U00B5 g/dL`.*, where are you printing the string?

Comment: Thanks Richard, I print it in the R console.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is less about printing the unicode character correctly than it is about correctly reading literal unicode text from a file and having it interpreted as a unicode string.

Comment: I agree.  Have you tried encoding the file with UTF-8?

Comment: If you encode the file with UTF-8 as @RichardScriven suggests, you can use `fileEncoding="UTF-8", allowEscapes=T` in your call to `read.csv()`.

Comment: If you literally have "\U00B5 g/dL" in a text file, that's not Unicode. That's just an ASCII slash followed by letters and numbers. It's unclear to me exactly what you have in your csv file. It would be nice if you provided a reproducible example (specifically showing the bytes of the file)

Comment: No. I just want something quick and simple on the special symbols.

Comment: @MrFlick: I suppose what I meant was correctly interpreting such ASCII sequences in the file as unicode strings when they get to R.

Comment: The example data frame you included works fine (at least for me). It's reading from the csv file that doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @AlexA. Yes. That's the problem! If I manually enter it, it works fine. But if I import from a `.csv` file. It would add  ` \\` .

Answer (score 66):

Well, first understand that certain characters in R must be escaped if they are outside the standard ASCII-characters. Typically this is done with a "\" character. That's why you need to escape this character when you write a string in R:

```
a <- "\" # error
a <- "\\" # ok.
```

The "\U" is a special indicator for unicode escaping. Note that there are no slashes or U's in the string itself when you use this escaping. It is just a shortcut to a specific character. Note:

```
a <- "\U00B5"
cat(a)
# µ
grep("U",a)
# integer(0)
nchar(a)
# [1] 1
```

This is very different than the string

```
a <- "\\U00B5"
cat(a)
# \U00B5
grep("U",a)
# [1] 1
nchar(a)
# [1] 6
```

Normally when you import a text file, you would encode non-ASCII character in whatever encoding is used by the file (UTF-8, or Latin-1 are the most common). They have special bytes to represent these characters. It's not "normal" for a text file to have an ASCII escape sequence for unicode characters. This is why R doesn't attempt to convert "\U00B5" to a unicode character because it assumes that if you had wanted a unicode character, you would have just used it directly.

The easiest way to re-interpet your ASCII character values would be to use the `stringi` package. For example

```
library(stringi)
a <- "\\U00B5"
stri_unescape_unicode(gsub("\\U","\\u",a, fixed=TRUE))
```

(the only catch is that we needed to convert "\U" to the more common "\u" so the function properly recognized the escape). You can do this to your imported data with

```
test$label <- stri_unescape_unicode(gsub("\\U","\\u",test$label, fixed=TRUE))
```