# fromCharCode() equivalent in R

Tags: r, unicode, utf

Do you knwo, if there's an equivalent to the JavaScript function [fromCharCode](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromcharcode.asp)? It converts Unicode values into characters.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29265172/print-unicode-character-string-in-r

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called `rawToChar` in R as described [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rawConversion.html) which do the required trick.

```
> rawToChar(as.raw(65))
[1] "A"
```

Comment: as.raw() unfortunately is out of range when I insert large Unicode numbers like 55357 (maximum is 255)

Comment: Do you know a function that does the job or have an idea where to look for it? Best regards

Comment: one workaround i came up with is [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/V8/vignettes/v8_intro.html) but `R` can't convert it to print in console

Comment: Can it write to file?

Comment: Yes, using `sink` it can be done but `R` doesn't seems to print `js` output in console !

Comment: So it seems like intToUtf8(56881) does the same as ct$eval(paste0('String.fromCharCode(',acc,')')).

Comment: But when I write() the numbers 55357 and 56881 to a text file using UTF-16 encoding, it becomes xEDxA0xBDxEDxB8. When I copy this from Notepad++ to the browser, it becomes  (and copying back to the file preserves the emoji). Any idea how to save this directly as ?