# Character accented with R

Tags: r

I am treating text with R (text classification) and I have a problem with some words in a french text , like for exemple this :

```
Charg\u00e9 d'\u00e9tude
```

How Can I do to resolve this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the method from this answer:"[Print unicode character string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29265172/print-unicode-character-string-in-r)". It looks like R is supposed to handle accents but maybe something is missing on the original file, and R is not recognizing the text as Unicode.

```
 library(stringi)
 stri_unescape_unicode("Charg\u00e9 d'\u00e9tude")
[1] "Chargé d'étude"
```