# Coverting unicode codeepoint format

Tags: r, encoding, character-encoding

Let's say that I have a character string containing bytes representing an emoji:

```
string <- "This is a test. U+1F600"
```

How can I transform it into

```
string <- "This is a test. \U0001F600"
```

So that I can render it as

```
utf8_print("This is a test \U0001F600")
[1] "This is a test ​"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29265172/print-unicode-character-string-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of a hack, but it works for your case:

```
string <- c("This is a test. U+1F600", "Another test")

# change U+XXXXYYYY to \UXXXXYYYY, quote and encode special characters
expr <- gsub("U[+]([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,8})", "\\\\U\\1",
             encodeString(string, quote = '"'))

# evaluate the string as an R expression
vapply(parse(text = expr, keep.source = FALSE), eval, "")
#> [1] "This is a test. \U0001f600" "Another test"
```

Comment: Wow! This is perfect. One more question. How would I render the shrugface emoji which isn't represented in unicode but by `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`?

Comment: That seems like an unrelated question that you should ask separately to make it easier for others to find the answer.