# set ... to na when using read_excel()

Tags: r, unicode, readxl

I am trying to read in excel files which use three horizontal dots to represent missing values, for example...

https://population.un.org/wpp/Download/Files/1_Indicators%20(Standard)/EXCEL_FILES/2_Fertility/WPP2019_FERT_F02_SEX_RATIO_AT_BIRTH.xlsx

Is it possible to set these to `NA` using `read_excel()`? I have tried different options for the `na` argument (see below), none which seem to work

```
d0 <- read_excel(path = "WPP2019_FERT_F02_SEX_RATIO_AT_BIRTH.xlsx)", 
                 # na = "...", # does not work
                 # na = "…", # copying the output does not work
                 # na = "U+2026", # unicode character does not work  
                 sheet = 2, skip = 16)
d0
# # A tibble: 255 x 21
#    Index Variant `Region, subreg~ Notes `Country code` Type  `Parent code` `1950-1955`
#    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>            <chr>          <dbl> <chr>         <dbl> <chr>      
#  1     1 Estima~ WORLD            NA               900 World             0 1.06       
#  2     2 Estima~ UN development ~ a               1803 Labe~           900 …          
#  3     3 Estima~ More developed ~ b                901 Deve~          1803 1.06       
#  4     4 Estima~ Less developed ~ c                902 Deve~          1803 1.06       
#  5     5 Estima~ Least developed~ d                941 Deve~           902 1.04       
#  6     6 Estima~ Less developed ~ e                934 Deve~           902 1.06       
#  7     7 Estima~ Less developed ~ NA               948 Deve~          1803 1.05       
#  8     8 Estima~ Land-locked Dev~ f               1636 Spec~          1803 1.04       
#  9     9 Estima~ Small Island De~ g               1637 Spec~          1803 1.05       
# 10    10 Estima~ World Bank inco~ NA              1802 Labe~           900 …          
# # ... with 245 more rows, and 13 more variables: `1955-1960` <chr>, `1960-1965` <chr>,
# #   `1965-1970` <chr>, `1970-1975` <chr>, `1975-1980` <chr>, `1980-1985` <chr>,
# #   `1985-1990` <chr>, `1990-1995` <chr>, `1995-2000` <chr>, `2000-2005` <chr>,
# #   `2005-2010` <chr>, `2010-2015` <chr>, `2015-2020` <chr>
```

Example column where `NA` is not being created, and values are not of numeric type...

```
d3 %>% select(`1950-1955`) %>% pull()
#  [1] "1.06"               "…"                  "1.06"               "1.06"              
#  [5] "1.04"               "1.06"               "1.05"               "1.04"              
#  [9] "1.05"               "…"                  "1.06"               "1.06"
```

Comment: Yes, it is. Use argument `na = "..."`

Comment: @RuiBarradas that does not seem to work for me (see the commented out part of my example `read_excel()` code)

Comment: For plan B, this worked for me - `d0 %>% 
  mutate_all(na_if, "…")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see here [Print unicode character string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29265172/print-unicode-character-string-in-r) the issue is with how you define the unicode char.

Try this:

```
readxl::read_xlsx("C:/Stack/WPP2019_FERT_F02_SEX_RATIO_AT_BIRTH.xlsx", sheet = 2, skip = 16, na="\U2026")
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple but effective, just convert the column to numeric after importing. Throws a warning, but who cares.

```
head(df)
#    something    v
# 1 -0.2168503 1.06
# 2  0.9863558    …
# 3  1.8623381 1.06
# 4 -1.0441477 1.06
# 5  0.4244308 1.04
# 6  1.5825152 1.06

df <- transform(df, v=as.numeric(v))
head(df)
#    something    v
# 1 -0.2168503 1.06
# 2  0.9863558   NA
# 3  1.8623381 1.06
# 4 -1.0441477 1.06
# 5  0.4244308 1.04
# 6  1.5825152 1.06
```

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(something = c(0.344600422686915, 1.12754949114835, 
0.264102711671497, -0.588052830551214, 0.916134405190614, 0.118418825652515, 
-1.5711759894206, 0.561452729377526, -0.27524305006459, -0.611306705421411, 
0.614179300117269, 0.765082495652037), v = c("1.06", "…", "1.06", 
"1.06", "1.04", "1.06", "1.05", "1.04", "1.05", "…", "1.06", 
"1.06")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```