# Special characters are not working in renderUI

Tags: r, shiny

I develop my Shiny application in French and therefore I use special characters like `"é"` (`e` with an accent) `"ê"`, `"Œ"`, and so on. But these special characters do not work in `renderUI`. For example, the category Pancréas (with `"é"`) doesn't work properly unless I remove the `é` and set the category as Pancreas. How can I make special characters work in renderUI?

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
TypeOfDisease<-c(rep("Infection",12),rep("Cancer",5),rep("Infection",14),
                 rep("Cancer",9),rep("Infection",8),rep("Cancer",7),rep("Infection",15),rep("Cancer",0),
                 rep("Infection",12),rep("Cancer",18))
Organ<-c(rep("Oesophage",17),rep("Stomach",23),rep("Lung",15),rep("Pancréas",15),rep("Liver",30))
data<-data.frame(TypeOfDisease,Organ)
addmargins(table(data$TypeOfDisease,dataF$Organ))

ui<-fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("Organ","Select the organ",
                  choices = c("Total",levels(data$Organ))),
      
      uiOutput("ui"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      
      fluidRow(
        column(5,tableOutput("table")),
        column(7,
               
               fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("matrix")),
               fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("Nrow"))
        )
      )
      
      
      
    )
  )
  
)


server<-function(input,output){
  
  
  output$ui<-renderUI(
    
    switch (input$Organ,
            
            "Total" = selectInput("TypeOfDis","Type of disease",
                                  choices = c("Total","Infection","Cancer")),
            "Oesophage" = selectInput("TypeOfDis","Type of disease",
                                      choices = c("Total","Infection","Cancer")),
            "Stomach" = selectInput("TypeOfDis","Type of disease",
                                    choices = c("Total","Infection","Cancer")),
            "Lung" = selectInput("TypeOfDis","Type of disease",
                                 choices = c("Total","Infection","Cancer")),
            "Pancréas" = selectInput("TypeOfDis","Type of disease",
                                     choices = c("Total")),
            "Liver" = selectInput("TypeOfDis","Type of disease",
                                  choices = c("Total","Infection","Cancer")),
    )
  )
  
  dataFilter<-reactive({
    
    if(input$TypeOfDis=="Total"&input$Organ=="Total"){
      data
    }else {
      
      
      if(input$TypeOfDis=="Total"){
        data[data$Organ==input$Organ,]
      }else if (input$Organ=="Total"){
        data[data$TypeOfDisease==input$TypeOfDis,]
      }else
        data[data$TypeOfDisease==input$TypeOfDis & data$Organ==input$Organ ,]
    
      
      
      } 
    
  })
  
  output$table<-renderTable ({dataFilter()})
  output$matrix<-renderPrint({addmargins(table(data$TypeOfDisease,dataF$Organ))})
  output$Nrow<-renderPrint({nrow(dataFilter())})
  
}



shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Your code runs fine for me too!

Comment: If you select `Pancreas`, the dataset is filtered but does the second `selectinput` window appear so that you can select the disease type?

Comment: Also, you need to use `req()` to eliminate the warnings in the console.

Comment: Yes, but the only choice is `Total` according to your data. Also, I use `unique()` in the first `selectInput` in `ui`, instead of `levels()`. Lastly, you have some typos... `dataF$`, instead of `data$` in a couple of places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your example above, the `"é"` displays properly for me. I would check to make sure the encoding is set to something like UTF-8 that allows for these characters. I'm not expert on encoding (and it can be a deep rabbit hole) but I would check first when parsing the code. For example, I copied your example into a blank file and ran source, this command appeared in the console `source('~/.active-rstudio-document', encoding = 'UTF-8', echo=TRUE)`

If that's set and still not displaying properly, launch the app into a browser and inspect the page source. Make sure UTF-8 is declared in the head element. Something such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

The last thing I can think of is then trying to either directly substitute the [HTML codes](https://www.lifewire.com/html-codes-french-characters-4062211) or Unicode value (`\U00E9`) into the label definitions. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29265172/print-unicode-character-string-in-r/29267201) discussing manually specifying Unicode in R strings maybe helpful.

Comment: My file is open with utf-8 encoding: this what I get with the inspector in `html>head> meta`:  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`