# How to add an icon or custom image to nodes in treeInput of shinyWidgets?

Tags: r, shiny, jstree, shinywidgets

This gives a basic tree. How could I add for example font-awesome icons or custom flags saved in a relative file path to these nodes?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

df <- data.frame(continent = c(rep("Europe", 2), rep("Asia", 2)),
                 country = c("France", "Germany", "China", "Japan"))

mytree <- create_tree(df, c("continent", "country"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyWidgets::treeInput("mytree", "mytree", mytree)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Do you have some examples of flag files?

Comment: Just ordinary png of svg files for example, saved locally on my machine. For example, assume I have flags saved on my machine for the 50 states of the US as png or svg from http://www.flagchart.net/flags/us-state.html.

Answer (score 3):

- In R you can use unicode characters in your script
  see this page [Unicode question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29265172/print-unicode-character-string-in-r)
- With the `emoji` package you can do the same with emoji, see [cran emoji package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emoji/emoji.pdf)

  Flag emoji are suitable in your example using the `flag` function in emoji
- For more complicated tasks consider vector graphics implemented in [grImport2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grImport2/)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(emoji)

df <- data.frame(continent = c(rep("\U2727", 2), rep("\U24B8", 2)),
                 country = c(flag("France"), flag("Germany"), flag("China"), flag("Japan")))

mytree <- create_tree(df, c("continent", "country"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyWidgets::treeInput("mytree", "mytree", mytree)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: here the result]

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, this looks good. Unfortunately for my real dataset the `flag` function from `emoji` does not contain all necessary flags, for example when I would like to use custom flags for a state or city. Do you suggest to use grImport2 for this or do you have a simpler solution in mind for flags/images saved locally?

Comment: Thank you @Lennyy for the feed back 
I also think that `emoji ` is a convenient package to add some icons to text 
the `grImport2`  is for adding icons to R plots 
I don't know if there is a way add a customized emoji

Answer (score 1):

If using another package is OK, {shinyTree} would be an option.

It can use **fontAwesome** icons or a set of {shinyTree} builtin icons.
You can also use HTML for item labels, thus offering to source your own images.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTree)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyTree::shinyTree('myShinyTree',
                       checkbox = TRUE,
                       themeIcons = FALSE,
                       theme = 'proton'
                       )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df <- data.frame(continent = c(rep("Letteria", 2), rep("Numberalia", 1)),
                   country = c("<img src = 'flag_A.png' width = '50px' /> A-Land", 
                               "<img src = 'flag_B.png' width = '50px' /> B-Country",
                               "<img src = 'flag_1.png' width = '50px' /> Uni Kingdom"
                               )
                   )

  output$myShinyTree <-  renderTree({
    tree_list <- dfToTree(df) ## dfToTree converts df into a hierarch. list
    attr(tree_list, 'stopened') <- TRUE
    ## set the 'stopened' attribute on each node to uncollapse the whole tree
    tree_list <- tree_list |>
      Map(f = \(.) {attr(., 'stopened') <- TRUE; .})

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Remember to put static content (here: the image files) in a subfolder `www` of your app's folder, so that Shiny will find it. Do *not* include the `www` in your path though. Example: reference file `www/flag_A.png` as `<img src = 'file.png'>`.

Output with custom images:

[image]

- find a repository of country flags [here](https://hampusborgos.github.io/country-flags/)
- With lots of symbols it might be convenient to add a class to your images, e.g. `<img class='flag' ...>` so that you can apply size, transparency etc. to all flags [via CSS](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html).